# Total y disyuntiva en Symfony

Tags: php, sql, symfony

Tengo que hacer una base de datos en PHP con Symfony y cuando creo la relación entre tablas, veo las clases de relaciones que puedes hacer, y estaba pensando si hay alguna manera de crear, automáticamente, una relación de tablas disyuntiva y total. Osea, una entidad que puede ser cliente o vendedor, pero no las dos cosas.

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer el CRUD y tal con Symfony? O tengo que crear las relaciones "a mano", al igual que el manejo de las tablas.

Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué has leído, [empezando por aquí](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html)? ¿Qué no has entendido? ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué dificultades o errores tienes? ¿En qué punto está tu diseño y dónde te encuentras bloqueado exactamente? Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta.